# 95th, 99th percentile on IIS log parser

Tags: iis, logparser

Is there a way to get the 95th or 99th percentile of response time with log parser? I am using log parser to parse IIS logs unfortunately, i can only see ready made queries for avg, max, min response time.

Comment: Import IIS log files to SQL Server, and then you can use `TOP`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get percentiles very easy from LogParser, but you can do it manually:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM $logDir\u_ex190314.log
WHERE [conditions]
```

This gives you the total number of requests. Then for 95th percentile, you calculate `(1 - 0.95) * COUNT(*)` and do another query:

```sql
SELECT TOP 123 time-taken
FROM $logDir\u_ex190314.log
WHERE [conditions]
ORDER BY time-taken DESC
```

Now, the *last* row in the result (or the minimum value in the set) is the 95th percentile "response time" (from IIS' point of view).

Another approach is to analyze the log files with a better tool, for example R, or to export to SQL Server or Excel.

Comment: While painful if we have large number of queries to execute, this is exactly what makes it the 95th percentile